# Do I need the doctype declaration?

Tags: doctype

Do I need a DOCTYPE declaration if my website is simple HTML? And do I need it on on EVERY HTML page?

What is the benefit of having it?

Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Having a `DOCTYPE` declaration tells the browser what version of HTML you are using.

The benefit is that the browser can better work with the HTML file and produce the expected result - if you don't have a `DOCTYPE`, the browser will go into [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and the resulting rendered page may very well not be what you expect.

In short - placing a `DOCTYPE` on a page ensures that the browser behaves according to the specification/standard. Not placing it on a page means that different browsers will behave differently.